# Shared hosting, multiple sites, can't log in to WP due to .htaccess redirection

Tags: htaccess, shared-hosting

I've got a shared hosting account with 3 separate domains on it. Each site is in its own directory, so via .htaccess there is a rewrite for each domain name to the corresponding folder.

When I try to log in to WP, the redirect URL that shows up in the address bar has the domain's folder in it.

Ex: www.domain1.com is under folder /domain1

Login redirect after login is `http://www.domain1.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain1.com%2Fdomain1%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

So it just brings me back to the login screen with no error message or anything...if I reset the password, however, I can log in successfully. But upon logout I get in the redirect loop again.

EDIT - this code is in .htaccess located in `/public_html/`. There is also another .htaccess inside `/public_html/domain1/` with the standard Wordpress lines.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain3.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain3/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you think it is due to the .htaccess, then it would be a good idea to post your source. There is not that much information, so we can say what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Why do you need a `.htaccess` to associate the domains with the directories? That’s wrong, you should do that in `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is an **.htaccess/server configuration** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: @ChipBennett I guess I figured I had to put some WP specific lines in .htaccess. These are existing sites which were working fine before I converted them to WP

Comment: @toscho there are a few domain aliases which are being pointed to these directories, if that makes a difference

Comment: @KevinSimper added `.htaccess` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');`

Putting this at the top of `wp-config.php` allows me to log in. Not sure if this is the proper way to set everything up, but it works...

**EDIT**

That only solved half of the problem. Permalinks were then broken.

@toscho had the *proper* suggestion for anyone who may see this and has a similar issue.

However, this hosting provider doesn't allow virtual hosts, so if you're in a similar situation what ended up working for me was a few more .htaccess lines (see below) combined with the `wp-config` modification above.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Copy and paste the following code into the .htaccess file
# in the public_html folder of your hosting account
# make the changes to the file according to the instructions.
# Do not change this line.

RewriteEngine on

# Change example.com to be your main domain.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/

# Don't change these line.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1

# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.php [L]
```